# Error when starting a new Linux VM in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have downloaded and installed Oracle VirtualBox. After creating a new Linux VM and trying to start it, I get an error message as follows:

> FATAL : NO Bootable Medium is Found ! System Halted.

Why is this happening?

What am I supposed to do while starting with a new VM for the first time if a pop-up window appears asking me to select the host drive?

What do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: You don't have Linux installed, you just have a machine. It's like your PC without Windows.

Comment: ok... but then what i should to run the linux VM ????

Comment: Download some Linux distribution and install it. Google is your friend.

Comment: i have one doubt.....  on the following link, i got information of my problem... but even after selecting the vBoxGuestAdditions.iso file ... still the same error is occurring...  can u pls help me??? http://superuser.com/questions/374653/creating-ubuntu-vm-with-virtualbox?rq=1

Comment: You need to install operating system, not Guest Additions. Grab an Ubuntu ISO and install from it.

Comment: u mean to say that i have to download the ubuntu iso separately ......right ????

Comment: @chinu That's correct. When you select "Linux" for the VM, that doesn't actually install Linux automatically, it simply preselects some configuration values to be suitable for running Linux. All new VMs you create start in a blank state, and you need to install the operating system (Ubuntu, or whatever flavour of Linux you want to run) yourself.

Comment: Exactly. There are hundreds of different Linux distributions and you have to download one of these, for example Ubuntu which is probably the most friendly one.

Comment: @chinu [more info on alots](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are having problem with your iso file or may be corrupted first of all before installing iso file please check iso hashsum using md5sum  and match with the hash file no in webiste if it doesn't matches try downloading.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to any linux distro site such as www.ubuntu.com.
2. Download the appropriate ISO.
3. Once downloaded go into the machine settings and go down to storage.
4. Select the icon that looks like a disc (CD) not 3 discs (Hard disk(Hard Drive)).
5. Select the ISO.
6. Start the machine.

Comment: No problem, if this solved the problem, feel free to mark it as the answer.